# Parse a file 2 lines at a time

Tags: python

Python beginner here. I have a file that looks like that (every field is \t separated):

```
chr1_1792868_SNP    Bcin01g04980    NON_SYNONYMOUS  NON_SYNONYMOUS[T](gene:Bcin01g04980|transcript:Bcin01g04980.1|P->S:225) ...         
chr1_1792869_SNP    Bcin01g04980    NON_SYNONYMOUS  NON_SYNONYMOUS[T](gene:Bcin01g04980|transcript:Bcin01g04980.1|P->L:225) ...                 
chr2_19719_SNP  Bcin02g00005    SYNONYMOUS  SYNONYMOUS[A](gene:Bcin02g00005|transcript:Bcin02g00005.1)  ...         
chr2_19811_SNP  Bcin02g00005    SYNONYMOUS  SYNONYMOUS[A](gene:Bcin02g00005|transcript:Bcin02g00005.1)  ...         
chr2_20024_SNP  Bcin02g00005    NON_SYNONYMOUS  NON_SYNONYMOUS[C](gene:Bcin02g00005|transcript:Bcin02g00005.1|S->A:331)             
chr2_20025_SNP  Bcin02g00005    SYNONYMOUS  SYNONYMOUS[A](gene:Bcin02g00005|transcript:Bcin02g00005.1)
```

I would like to parse through the file and compare 2 lines at a time and compare a value between them.

So in this case, I woud like to compare the line 1 and 2, check if there is "SYNONYMOUS" in the 3rd field in each of them. If yes, I would do some thing, if no (this case) I move on to the 3rd and 4th line (where this time the comparison of the two "SYNONYMOUS" values be positive) and I would select the first value of the line to do some more thing (compare with another dictionnary).

I thought about doing something something like that:

```
with open ('file.txt') as mutmut_mutants:
    for line1 in mutmut_mutants:
        line2 = next(mutmut_mutants)
        print type(line1)
        print line2+ "line2"
```

But the problem is that I am dealing with lines of string instead of element of list (on line/element in a big list). Dealing with a list seems easier than with strings/regex. I then thought of this:

```
with open ('file.txt') as mutmut_mutants:
    for i in csv.reader(mutmut_mutants, delimiter='\t'):
        for k,(l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(i[0::2], i[1::2])):
            print str(zip(i[0::2], i[1::2]))
```

But I can't make it work (and I don't get the zip and the i[0::2] very clearly). What I'm trying to do is : compare lines 2 by 2, and if SYNONYMOUS in both lines get the first strings (chrX_XXXXX_SNP) of each line.

Any thought on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the split method of the string. Loop through the file as you do in your first code example, and then split each line on tabs with:

```
ls = []
with open ('file.txt') as mutmut_mutants:
    for line1 in mutmut_mutants:
        fields = line1.split('\t')
        ls.append(fields)
```

Splitting the strings on the tabs will give you a list of each field that is separated by tabs. You can then append it to a list and process it however you want. So for example to access the third field of the fourth line you would just do `ls[3][2]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: third field in fourth line is `ls[3][2]` it's zero-indexed :)

Answer (score 0):

It will probably depend on the weight of your text file (you can have a really big number of SNPs ...).

If you can load the whole file in one variable:

```
# Store everything in one variable - readlines() to have a list of lines
mutmut_mutants = open('file.txt', "r").readlines()

# The number of lines
n = len(mutmut_mutants)

# Loop two by two (end at n-1 or n-2)
for i in range(0, n-1, 2):
    first_line = mutmut_mutants[i]
    second_line = mutmut_mutants[i+1]

    # Split those lines (the separator is \t ?) and compare what's
    # inside, for example
    syn1 = first_line.split("\t")[2]
    syn2 = second_line.split("\t")[2]
    if syn1 == syn2 and syn1 == "SYNONYMOUS":
        # Do stuff
```

If you can't load everything in one variable. Hum. I probably can't suggest something even remotely beautiful. Hope this helps.

Comment: close your file! :P

Answer (score 0):

You have an iterator that produces 1 item at a time, which is the file object.

You need an iterator that wraps that one and generates 2 items at a time.

Here's a naive approach:

```
def even_by_two(incoming):
    while True:
        one = next(incoming)
        two = next(incoming)
        yield (one, two)
    # This will break on a StopIteration exception,
    # which is ok for a generator.
    # The odd item at the end will be silently missed.
```

A demo:

```
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
  for one, two in even_by_two(f):
    print ("one -> ", one)
    print ("two -> ", two)
```

The problem, of course, is that if the number of lines is not even, the last line will be lost.

Here's a less naive approach that cuts the input iterator by chunks of given size; the last chunk can be smaller.

```
def by_n(how_much, incoming):
    while True: # We need a post-condition, got no do-while in Python.
        result = []
        count = 0
        # The `for` will advance the iterator, but not past its end.
        for value in incoming:  
            result.append(value)
            count += 1
            if count >= how_much:
                break
        if result:
            yield result
        else:  # We got nothing from the iterator, it must be over.
            break

>>> list(by_n(2, iter('abcdefg')))
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
>>> list(by_n(5, iter('abcdefg')))
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]
```

Note that the input must be a generator / iterator, e.g. a file, or a `csv.reader`. A simple list or a string won't work, hence `iter(...)` above that produces an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that using `csv.reader` is a better way to parse the CSV file than doing it by hand. However, you can work with the iterator explicitly, rather than using a `for` loop, much like you did with the `file` object.

```
with open ('file.txt') as mutmut_mutants:
    reader = csv.reader(mutmut_mutants, delimiter='\t')
    while True:
        try:
            l1 = next(reader)
            l2 = next(reader)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

        # Use l1 and l2 here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `pandas` module to read the file in as a dataframe (although you might have a little trouble getting your column names sorted out.

Assuming you aren't familiar with pandas (put it on your list of things to learn, it's well worth it for anything data related) you might try something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

indexes = []
for i, line in enumerate(data[:-1]):
    if (line.split('    ')[2] == data[i+1].split('    ')[2]) and line.split('    ')[2] == 'SYNONYMOUS':
        indexes.append(i)

for i in indexes:
     print data[i], data[i+1] # or do whatever you want with those
```

indexes is a list of the positions of the first of each pair of lines in your file that match your conditions.

Depending on what you want to do pandas might be a better way something like (and this is just a guess because I can't load you example into pandas because of the different lenghts of lines (due to the ...))

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', header=0) # might be header=None

df.columns=['mutation', 'strain', 'syn', 'info']

match_df = df.loc[df['syn'] == df['syn'].shift(1)] # might need to specify axis= for .shift
```

this would give you a dataframe of (again) the first of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two array and store there the current line and the before line:

```
list = []
list_before =[]
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as mutmut_mutants:
 list.append(mutmut_mutants.readline().split())
 print(list)
```

Then compare if the current and the before list have in the same position the word SYNNONYMOUS.

```
print(list[0][0][:3]) = "cnr"
print(list[0][0][-4:]) = "_SNP"
```

hope if it helps